# AndroidManifest merger failed on merging path-permission

Tags: android, android-studio, android-manifest, manifest-merging

I have imported some [AOSP code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/providers/ContactsProvider/+/master/AndroidManifest.xml#29) into my application, and during execution of `processDebugAndroidTestManifest` task, it throws `java.lang.RuntimeException`:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':contacts_common:processDebugAndroidTestManifest'.
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Manifest merger failed : Attribute path-permission@pathPrefix value=(/search_suggest_query) from [gcs:contacts_provider:unspecified] AndroidManifest.xml:31:17-59
>       is also present at [gcs:contacts_provider:unspecified] AndroidManifest.xml:34:17-62 value=(/search_suggest_shortcut).
>       Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:pathPrefix"' to  element at manifestMerger6750235787399637901.xml to override.

It is strange, because I'm sure that some time ago a manifest merger did not raise objections.

I can't add `'tools:replace="android:pathPrefix"'` element, because I need to use both, permissions, just as in AOSP.

How can I use two different `pathPrefixes` in provider?

Here is my `provider`:

```
<provider
        android:name="some_name"
        android:authorities="some_authorities"
        android:exported="false"
        android:label="@string/provider_label"
        android:multiprocess="false" >
        <path-permission
            android:pathPrefix="/search_suggest_query"
            android:readPermission="android.permission.GLOBAL_SEARCH" />
        <path-permission
            android:pathPrefix="/search_suggest_shortcut"
            android:readPermission="android.permission.GLOBAL_SEARCH" />
        <path-permission
            android:pathPattern="/contacts/.*/photo"
            android:readPermission="android.permission.GLOBAL_SEARCH" />

        <grant-uri-permission android:pathPattern=".*" />
</provider>
```

Using `./gradlew assembleDebug` works fine. Exception is being thrown only in Android Studio.

I'm using Android Studio 2.1.1, build gradle tools 2.0.0 and 2.1.0.